# Algebraically determining the mod 2 cohomology of $\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^\infty$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

I am currently working on an exercise in May's Concise, which is to use homological algebra to determine the cohomology ring $H^*(\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^\infty; \mathbb{Z}_2)$.

So far I have the following results.

(i) The cochain groups $C^*(\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^\infty; \mathbb{Z}_2)$ are isomorphic to the $\mathrm{Hom}_\mathbb{Z[\pi]}(C_*(S^\infty), \mathbb{Z}_2)$ where $\pi = \pi_1(\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^\infty) = \mathbb{Z}_2$ is the fundamental group. The group ring $\mathbb{Z}[\pi]$ acts on the chains of the universal cover $S^\infty$ of $\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^\infty$ in the usual way and acts on the coefficient ring $\mathbb{Z}_2$ so that the action of elements in $\pi$ are trivial.

(ii) The action of $\mathbb{Z}[\pi]$ on $C_*(S^\infty)$ mentioned above makes $C_*(S^\infty)$ into a complex of free $\mathbb{Z}[\pi]$-modules. Since $S^\infty$ is aspherical, the augmented chain complex of $S^\infty$ $(\cdots \to C_1(S^\infty) \to C_0(S^\infty) \overset{\epsilon}{\to} \mathbb{Z} \to 0 )$ can then be considered as a free $\mathbb{Z}[\pi]$-resolution of $\mathbb{Z}$. Consequently, with the isomorphism in (i), we have $H^*(\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^\infty ; \mathbb{Z}_2) \cong \mathrm{Ext}^*_{\mathbb{Z}[\pi]} (\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}_2) $.

Now using these information I am asked to use algebra to determine the ring structure of $H^*(\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^\infty; \mathbb{Z}_2)$. I presume I must compute the Ext groups given in (ii) using the $\mathbb{Z}[\pi]$-resolution $\cdots \to \mathbb{Z}[\pi] \to \mathbb{Z}[\pi] \to \mathbb{Z} \to 0$ where the maps $\partial: \mathbb{Z}[\pi] \to \mathbb{Z}[\pi]$ and $\epsilon: \mathbb{Z}[\pi]\to \mathbb{Z}$ are given by $1, \pi \mapsto (\pi -1)$ and $1, \pi \mapsto 1$, respectively. Yet I am having trouble calculating the product structure described in p.143.

I would greatly appreciate if someone could help me understand how to explicitly compute such products in the Ext groups only using homological algebra. For the purpose of this problem, I am less interested in approaches exploiting the geometry of $\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^\infty$ to obtain information about its cup product structure.

Comment: Note the orientations of the cells. If $t$ generates $\mathbb{Z}_2$ then the differential on $C_n(S^\infty)$ is multiplication by $(1-t)$ if $n$ is odd and multiplication by $(1+t)$ if $n$ is even.